# How to "remove diacritics" from Arabic text in unicode?

Tags: arabic, unicode, diacritics

I have put together [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/lancejpollard28/pen/oNazNaj) with a rendering demonstrating how I am "stripping diacritics" from Arabic text. Here is the main code doing the stripping:

```
const map = {
  'آ': 'ا',
  'أ': 'ا',
  'إ': 'ا',
  'ا': 'ا',
  'ٱ': 'ا',
  'ٲ': 'ا',
  'ٳ': 'ا',
  'ؤ': 'و',
  'ئ': 'ى',
  'ؽ': 'ؽ',
  'ؾ': 'ؾ',
  'ؿ': 'ؿ',
  'ي': 'ى',
  'ب': 'ب',
  'ت': 'ت',
  'ؠ': 'ؠ',
  'ة': 'ه',
  'ث': 'ث',
  'ج': 'ج',
  'ح': 'ح',
  'خ': 'خ',
  'د': 'د',
  'ذ': 'ذ',
  'ر': 'ر',
  'ز': 'ز',
  'س': 'س',
  'ش': 'ش',
  'ص': 'ص',
  'ض': 'ض',
  'ط': 'ط',
  'ظ': 'ظ',
  'ع': 'ع',
  'غ': 'غ',
  'ػ': 'ک',
  'ؼ': 'ک',
  'ف': 'ف',
  'ق': 'ق',
  'ك': 'ك',
  'ګ': 'ك',
  'ڬ': 'ك',
  'ڭ': 'ڭ',
  'ڮ': 'ك',
  'ل': 'ل',
  'م': 'م',
  'ن': 'ن',
  'ه': 'ه',
  'و': 'و',
  'ى': 'ى',
  'ٸ': 'ى',
  'ٵ': 'ءا', // hamza alef?
  'ٶ': 'ءو', // hamza waw?
  'ٹ': 'ٹ',
  'ٺ': 'ٺ',
  'ٻ': 'ٻ',
  'ټ': 'ت',
  'ٽ': 'ت',
  'پ': 'پ',
  'ٿ': 'ٿ',
  'ڀ': 'ڀ',
  'ځ': 'ءح',
  'ڂ': 'ح',
  'ڃ': 'ڃ',
  'ڄ': 'ڄ',
  'څ': 'ح',
  'چ': 'چ',
  'ڇ': 'ڇ',
  'ڈ': 'ڈ',
  'ډ': 'د',
  'ڊ': 'د',
  'ڋ': 'د',
  'ڌ': 'ڌ',
  'ڍ': 'ڍ',
  'ڎ': 'ڎ',
  'ڏ': 'د',
  'ڐ': 'د',
  'ڑ': 'ڑ',
  'ڒ': 'ر',
  'ړ': 'ر',
  'ڔ': 'ر',
  'ڕ': 'ر',
  'ږ': 'ر',
  'ڗ': 'ر',
  'ژ': 'ژ',
  'ڙ': 'ڙ',
  'ښ': 'س',
  'ڛ': 'س',
  'ڜ': 'س',
  'ڝ': 'ص',
  'ڞ': 'ص',
  'ڟ': 'ط',
  'ڠ': 'ع',
  'ڡ': 'ڡ',
  'ڢ': 'ڡ',
  'ڣ': 'ڡ',
  'ڤ': 'ڤ',
  'ڥ': 'ڡ',
  'ڦ': 'ڦ',
  'ڧ': 'ق',
  'ڨ': 'ق',
  'ک': 'ک',
  'ڪ': 'ڪ',
  'گ': 'گ',
  'ڰ': 'گ',
  'ڱ': 'ڱ',
  'ڲ': 'گ',
  'ڳ': 'ڳ',
  'ڴ': 'گ',
  'ڵ': 'ل',
  'ڶ': 'ل',
  'ڷ': 'ل',
  'ڸ': 'ل',
  'ڹ': 'ن',
  'ں': 'ں',
  'ڻ': 'ڻ',
  'ڼ': 'ن',
  'ڽ': 'ن',
  'ھ': 'ه',
  'ڿ': 'چ',
  'ۀ': 'ه',
  'ہ': 'ہ',
  'ۂ': 'ءہ',
  'ۃ': 'ہ',
  'ۄ': 'و',
  'ۅ': 'ۅ',
  'ۆ': 'ۆ',
  'ۇ': 'ۇ',
  'ۈ': 'ۈ',
  'ۉ': 'ۉ',
  'ۊ': 'و',
  'ۋ': 'ۋ',
  'ی': 'ی',
  'ۍ': 'ي',
  'ێ': 'ي',
  'ۏ': 'و',
  'ې': 'ې',
  'ۑ': 'ي',
  'ے': 'ے',
  'ۓ': 'ے',
  'ە': 'ە',
  'ۺ': 'ش',
  'ۻ': 'ض',
  'ۼ': 'ۼ',
  'ۿ': 'ه'
}

function removeDiacritics(text) {
  const symbols = [...text]
  const result = []
  for (const symbol of symbols) {
    if (map[symbol]) {
      result.push(symbol)
    }
  }
  return result.join('')
}
```

If you take a look at the [codepen](https://codepen.io/lancejpollard28/full/oNazNaj), it should show you [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2yQY.jpg):

[image]

**What mappings can I simplify, and what ones am I doing wrong from that list?** That is the entire [Unicode Arabic block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_(Unicode_block)).

I think this is a linguistics question because it is about how to interpret the written script (albeit in my case for a coding purpose). Only a linguist, and not a coder, would deeply know how to "strip diacritics" properly from text.

Comment: I’ve never tried this (or worked on Arabic text at all, really), but aren’t Arabic diacritics supposed to be combining characters that you can just remove from a string using regex? If you have precomposed glyphs in the string, you should be able to normalise it first, then regex out the diacritics. That would, in theory at least, reduce the entire stripping code to just two lines.

Comment: Some are combining characters, some are precomposed. But as I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76045125/169992), I am not sure what some of the precomposed characters should be transformed into. So I thought I'd ask here to clarify exactly what to do with the precomposed characters. I don't think it's as easy as it seems.

Comment: Well, I can’t help you with that – the functions of Arabic diacritics and which should be considered dispensable is way out of my bailiwick. But in general, one of the benefits of Unicode normalisation is that things like that have already been taken into account by people who are highly qualified to do so. [Here’s a quick Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r62onx0g/) that shows the removal based on normalising the text to `NFD` (not sure if `NFKD` would be better here – they give the same result on the random sample I used).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is predominantly a programming rather than linguistics question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue is defining what you mean by "diacritic". You strip the under-dots from yeh, but not from beh.You strip off hamza, maddah, nukta but preserve the diacritic in Farsi ؽ.You are not reducing the script to [rasm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasm). I don;t know how you would know that you have the correct mapping: perhaps this is an Arabic-coders internal issue, i.e. you are trying to match an unpublished "standard". Somebody once said "I don't know the exact definition of what is a diacritic and what is not".

Perhaps the best bet is to map to rasm, and see if Arabic-script-using coders think that is correct. Alternatively, remove tashkil only.